# Android Httpurlconnection issue - nothing happens after .connect

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am kind of new in android development and I am having a weird issue.

The following code is supposed to work:

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/test.html");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();  
System.out.println("code: "+code);
```

The problem is, after I do the connection.connect(); nothing happens, even if I add a textX.setText() after the connect, I am not able to do any action.

Any idea what might be the issue?

This is my whole method, all I am trying to do is get some text from the API, which says "OK" actually, but I am not able to make it work.

```
public void conn (View view)
    {
        TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text2.setText("connecting...");
        String output="";
        //All working until here
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            output="about to connect";
            text2.setText(output);
            url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/localweb/api/api.php");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            text2.append("\nabout to get code");
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            text2.setText(Integer.toString(code));

            //urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //urlConnection.connect();
            //output=urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
            //text2.setText(output);


            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                System.out.print(current);
                output=output+current;
            }
            //text2.setText(output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please learn networking basics - what localhost(127.0.0.1) means ... obviously unless http server is not on the device itself this will not work

Comment: @Selvin, 127.0.0.1 was put to post it here, it is my public IP what goes in there

Comment: Then obviously you should read logcat output

Comment: And where does youd app run?

Comment: You will  have a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: @greenapps, thanks for the help, this was the issue. I put now the function as AsyncTask and remodeled a little bit the structure, now I am getting the response I need from the API. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't something 'wrong' with the http client code, the issue is that you cannot launch the httpurlclient from the parent thread as I was trying to do, it must be executed in the background through an AsyncTask, after moving all the httpurlconnection stuff into an additional async function now I am able to get all the web details I needed.